# How can i customize the spinner?

Tags: android, spinner

My problem is straight-forward.
I have a default spinner in android API 19.

But i want to customize it to make it have a border and also a triangular shape at the end pointing at the bottom. (Like the spinner with old versions of android).

I have this spinner: http://androidopentutorials.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/android-4-spinner.jpg?f9f065

But I want the spinner to be like this: http://lh4.ggpht.com/-DwIrYX29Rzg/TsPtjLkIkLI/AAAAAAAAAjs/m3GvtKmRDGo/firstLayout_thumb.png?imgmax=800

How can i customize the spinner?

I have searched for tutorials online but i got only those custom spinner with image and text together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this tutorial: http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/03/easily-create-a-default-custom-styled-spinner-android/
Basically, what you need is a 9-patch that you will use as a background of your `Spinner`.

The steps are fairly simple:

1. Get your 9-patches ready.
2. Create a `<selector>` that represents the stats of your `Spinner` by using these 9-patches.
3. Set the `<selector>` as the background for your `Spinner`.

The caveat to my approach is that you will have to set the background for every `Spinner` you use. If you want to 'do it once, use it everywhere', follow the tutorial approach where the author uses a custom theme.